# A new expression Requires (), [], or {} C# Constructor Error

Tags: c#, syntax, constructor, error-handling

```
public class ScreenManager
{

    #region Variables
    private static List<BaseScreen> Screens = new List<BaseScreen>();
    private static List<BaseScreen> NewScreens = new List<BaseScreen>
    #endregion

    public ScreenManager()
    {

    }
 }
```

The "public" part of the Constructor is being underlined in red and saying "A new expression Requires (), [], or {}" but I clearly have the () after it.

Any Solutions?

Comment: You clearly don't have it!

Comment: "I clearly have the () after **it.**" I used to be with it, but then they changed what *it* was. Now what I'm with isn't *it*, and what's *it* seems weird and scary to me. © Grandpa Simpson

Answer (score 4):

Basic syntax error. Replace:

```
private static List<BaseScreen> NewScreens = new List<BaseScreen>
```

with

```
private static List<BaseScreen> NewScreens = new List<BaseScreen>();
```

Comment: Oh My god, Thanks :D First post here, you guys are really fast :D